# Is it possible to code a website only browsable by IE?

Tags: web

It is not a question to describe in detail. I just to clarify my concept.

Is it possible to code a website only browseable by IE?

Comment: Yup, you can try using [Conditionl comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Do a redirect, or just make another page within:

```
<!--[if IE]>
// in here only IE will look, therefore you can isolate the other browsers from IE then redirect IE to another page, or just make this page blank and it can generate a page from withing the comment //
<![endif]-->
```

Yes it is possible

*This is a conditional comment*

Answer (score 0):

You could put everything inside an IE [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). Browsers other than IE will treat this all as a comment, only IE will process it as HTML.